# Is object hierarchy navigation causing problems with KO?

Tags: knockout.js

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edsinek/5EP4n/

I'm stuck on two issues.

First, in my MaterialLineItem data structure, I have a reference to the selected material object (material - where Material is defined as its own object).  From that, I want to either show the material name in a span or selected in a select.  I've got the conditional stuff working, but the span isn't showing the text.  I am confused why navigating down the object hierarchy doesn't work.

Second, I'm trying to make visible the Other Material text box based on the selection of the Material select.  Originally, I had the isOtherMaterial function setup as a computed on the MaterialLineItem structure (which I think looks nicer) but that didn't work so I tried another approach which is to make it a root function - which doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot to add parens `()` when accessing an observable again. You need: `text: material().materialName`
2. You're referencing `material.otherMaterial` but your model only has otherMaterial defined at the line-item level. also you forgot the parens here again - and also in your `isOtherMaterial` function. I don't know if the changes I made regarding otherMaterial make sense, but your current code didn't make much sense either :P

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/5EP4n/5/

Comment: Thanks @antishok. Still getting used to that syntax. isOtherMaterial isn't working, even in your fiddle. I played around with it but still no go for me. I even moved isOtherMaterial to the Material object (which makes more sense from an OO POV) and call material().isOtherMaterial from the HTML.  No go. Tried using 'this' in the computed function but it was referencing window...  http://jsfiddle.net/edsinek/ENHYG/172/

Comment: My idea with the code structure was that materials and containers are a static list where line items is variable (up to the user). If the user selects "other material" from the material drop down, they should be able to enter their own custom material in the text box.  So, I only want to show the other material text box if the selected material (from the drop down) is other material.

Comment: I think this fiddle makes more sense from the OO perspective and the description I just gave:  http://jsfiddle.net/edsinek/ENHYG/176/

Comment: When making a computed you need pass the "this" context as an argument, e.g. `this.c = ko.computed({...}, this)`. Another issue is that when adding a new line, the initial `material` of that line is undefined, so binding with `visible: material().isOtherMaterial` will throw an error. So I changed it to `visible: material() && material().isOtherMaterial`. [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/ENHYG/179/)

Comment: Actually it makes more sense to leave isOtherMaterial in the line-item object, because it's a property of the line-item if it has a "regular" or "other" material (and maybe you should apply this further..). Now the binding string is just `visible: isOtherMaterial`, and isOtherMaterial checks the line-item's material. [-fiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/ENHYG/180/)